# Can "safer" be used as a noun?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

The word "safer" can refer to several different meanings such as well-being, which would usually be placed as an adjective. It is similarly associated with being cautious, trustworthy, or reliable as the same part of speech.

As a noun "safe" can refer to the very same meanings. As a noun the word "safe" can have the same meaning if the sentence is structured differently. It is a physical thing where one can keep one's valuables.

My question is can the word "safer" be used as a noun in any context? I cannot think of any. Can anyone else?

Comment: Like many words, it may mean something in a limited context, but not generally. If there were two varieties of moving equipment, one extra-heavy duty for moving big things like safes, that might well end up as the "safe type", meaning "the type to use for safes". And for there to _safer_ is not far at all -- equipment uses the _-er_ suffix extensively, and is often named locally. The more specialized, the more localized, and usually the weirder as well.

Comment: I don't know how common the usage is, but *A condom (also called a rubber, prophylactic, or [**safe**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0SdHAAAAMAAJ&q=%22called+a+rubber,+prophylactic,+or+safe%22&dq=%22called+a+rubber,+prophylactic,+or+safe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AzzFVK-JKcSQ7AaJxIDgBA&redir_esc=y)) is a thin sheath that is placed over the penis to collect the man's semen so that it does not enter the vagina*

Comment: Logically, were safer to be a word, it would most probably mean one who uses or makes safes. I don't think it is a word, though I haven't checked even one dictionary.

Comment: ... Though I can't find nounal _safer_ in any [free] online dictionary I've checked in , the noun apparently is used: 'MW Safers is a brand within Century that provides safers for both round magnet SLS single locking systems and DLS double locking systems.' It sounds like a part of a lock.

Comment: This is a little bit of a cheat but, [here's a sentence](https://books.google.com/books?id=MD4a1wgxpeUC&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=%22the+safer+must%22&source=bl&ots=5ynIh3J7Nm&sig=h7dnL8D2Ay7YvpLy26i8NPSgXT0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LEDFVOOOMYqogwSfsISwDw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22the%20safer%20must%22&f=false) : "The SAFER must be absolutely reliable." where SAFER stands for "Simplified Aid for Extravehicular Rescue"

Comment: "While walking the streets of New York, Morley Safer was accosted by a mugger.  Although he was hit over the head, Safer is reported to have suffered no serious injuries."

Comment: The instance that Edwin Ashworth cited is a translucent lockable box used to display mechandise such that it cannot be shoplifted. It is made by a Swedish company.  I don't know whether "safer" is a trademark or a common English term in Europe. I can imagine the term meaning "something that makes something else into a safe" but that is only a guess

Comment: This is English. Any verb can be nouned, in theory. In practice, however, the resulting word may not be in common use. This appears to be such a case -- the word would probably be understood in context but would usually not be the correct word idiomatically.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently not. By and large, "safer" is an adjective in its comparative form:

- "It is always safer to keep your money in the bank."
- "Contrary to popular belief, it's generally safer to travel by air".

As John Lawler points out in his comment, however, in a specific context one might use the word as a noun.

Comment: This adds nothing to the comments already given. It's also unsupported.